# VB Copy command opens update values window

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub WorksheetCopy()
    ' Dimensions variables as workbooks
Dim WbSource As Workbook
Dim WbDest As Workbook
Dim CopyYear As Integer
Dim YearCount As Integer
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim YearDate As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turns off notifications

Set WbSource = ThisWorkbook ' Sets this workbook as the Source Workbook
Set WbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\U486474\Desktop\Lv 2 Templates\HoursLog.xlsx") ' Sets the Destination workbook
                                                    ' hard coded to a specific file location

CopyYear = 2015 ' Sets first year to copy data minus 1 year for counter

For YearCount = 1 To 3  ' Loop to define number of years report is to copy  ' Currently the loop runs 3 times for 2016, 2017 and 2018
    CopyYear = CopyYear + 1 ' increments per year
    YearDate = CopyYear ' converts variable to a string to be use in named fields

    Debug.Print " CopyYear " & CopyYear & "     YearCount " & YearCount & "   YearDate " & YearDate ' just for testing

    Set WS1 = WbSource.Sheets(YearDate)     ' Sets the Source Workbook / Worksheet and the year to be copied from
    Set WS2 = WbDest.Sheets(YearDate)       ' Sets Destination Workbook / Worksheet and the year to be pasted to

      WS1.Cells.Copy WS2.Cells       ' command to copy from the source worksheet and paste into the destination worksheet

Next

    WbDest.Close True 'Saves and Closes destination workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True   ' Turns Notifications back on

End Sub
```

What happens is that when it gets to the copy command it opens the update values window. This stops the routine from woking until you cancel the select window.
Other than that the routine works fine.
I am trying to automate this routine and do not want any user inputs.

Secondly what i have been trying ti figure out is how to paste as values.
The cells contain formulas. i just need the values for the report.
From searching the forums

```
WS1.Range("A1:CZ14400").Copy
WS2.Range("A1:CZ14400").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

in place of the copy command line

It did not work and i get a out of memory error.
The file is large..  32 meg

And help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: For the second bit, you can use `WS2.Range("A1:CZ14400").value=WS1.Range("A1:CZ14400").value` which is more efficient than copying and pasting (you should have used values rather than formulas).

Comment: `ScreenUpdating` doesn't block notifications (but does help with speed of a macro that does a lot of screen changes like formatting and copy/paste!).  Try adding: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: I tried those commands earlier.... but must have been doing them wrong..  Your magic touch fixed both my issues   Thank You